# Download files with differents extensions with bash and wget

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, wget

I'm trying to download images with differents extensions with `bash` and `wget`. I have to target the files directly because i have a 403 error on the parents folders, so i can't use the `-A` option by targeting the parent folder.

For now i have the following code which works fine for the `.jgp` but if the next file is a `.png` for example my loop breaks and continue to the next folder so the `.png` in the current folder are not downloaded.

```
for i in {1..945}; do
    for j in {01..100}; do
        j=`printf '%02d' $j`
        ret=$(wget -O ch${i}-${j}.jpg https://www.domain.co/uploads/chapters/chapitre-${i}/${j}.jpg 2>&1)
        if [[ "$ret" =~ 404\ Not\ Found ]]; then
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to download the file regardless of its extension.

**EDIT:**

So here's my final snippet for those who are interested.
What it does is:

recursively crawl a folder and its content

check if the file is a `.jpg` or a `.png` and then rename it accordingly

goes back at the previous loop (parent folder) if 404

delete empty files created with 404

```
for i in {245..945}; do
    for j in {01..60}; do
        j=`printf '%02d' $j`
        ret=$(wget -O ch${i}-${j}.jpg https://www.yourdomain.co/uploads/parentfoldernumber-${i}/image-${j}.jpg 2>&1)
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then 
            ret=$(wget -O ch${i}-${j}.png https://www.yourdomain.co/uploads/parentfoldernumber-${i}/image-${j}.png 2>&1) 
        fi
        if [[ "$ret" =~ 404\ Not\ Found ]]; then
            break
        fi
    done
    find . -type f -empty -delete
done
```

Comment: You haven't handled the code what will happen if a png file comes...?
If ref doesnt find the jpg then the loop breaks As of IF condition mentioned. 
You need to handle or catch the part where png comes.

Comment: Yes because i'm still searching how to do it. It's the first bash script i'm not familiar with the syntax sorry. Is there a way of puting extensions in a variable?

Comment: Do we know what extensions will be present there? or we just know the file name, not the extension? 
Because if we know the file extension type we could do something like switch case to check the extensions and download whichever is present.

Comment: From what I saw, only jpgs and pngs but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I tried something, Maybe this will help you,

`$?` is command of bash, which returns the output of last command ran.

If *.png is not found, the output won't be 0. 
You could case it with that, 


`if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then

                ret=$(wget -O ch${i}-${j}.png http://localhost/project/wp-content/uploads/2018/${i}/${j}.png 2>&1)
        fi

        if [[ "$ret" =~ 404\ Not\ Found ]]; then
           echo "breaking code"
            break
        fi
`
Hope this helps you.


Add this command after your wget code for jpg

Comment: THANKS it works just fine. Now, i know i'm pushing a bit but i was wondering if i could tell wget not to download the file if 404. Because for now, it is downloaded with a 0 octet size. I'll go and check the documentation you don't have to answer this one ;)
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried something, Maybe this will help you,

`$?` is command of bash, which returns the output of last command ran.

If *.png is not found, the output won't be 0. 
You could case it with that,

`if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
                ret=$(wget -O ch${i}-${j}.png http://localhost/l4urstyle/wp-content/uploads/2018/${i}/${j}.png 2>&1)
        fi`

```
    if [[ "$ret" =~ 404\ Not\ Found ]]; then
       echo "breaking code"
        break
    fi
```

Hope this helps you.
If this worked. Please accept the answer. :D 
And about file being downloaded of 0 octet size. I will think of something and let you know how i can help you with that.

Happy Coding :D